# RequireJS load Wicket library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, wkt

I am using the library [Wicket](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket) for map stuff. If I reference it as the script tag as normal, It works fine. Working link as below.

> https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

The problem comes when our project using RequireJS for module loader.

This is the following code that I tried.

```
require.config({    
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths: {
        'wicket': '/Vendor/Wicket/wicket',
        'wicketGmap3': '/Vendor/Wicket/wicket-gmap3'
    },
    shim: {
        wicket: {
            exports: 'Wkt'
        },
        wicketGmap3: {            
            deps: ['wicket']
        }          
    },
});
require(['wicket', 'wicketGmap3'],(Wkt) => {
    $(() => {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

The error is still as below.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Wkt is not defined at wicket-gmap3.js:744

Has anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wicket.js` file has a call to `define`. So setting a `shim` for it is useless, because `shim` is meaningful only for non-AMD "modules" (i.e. files that are not really modules but which we want to behave as if they were). AMD modules call `define`.

On the other hand `wicket-gmap3.js` is not an AMD-module. So you *do* need the `shim` for it. However, it depends on `Wkt` being present in the global space. The logic in `wicket.js` is such that when it calls `define` it does not set `Wkt` in the global space. (Which *is* the correct behavior for well-behaved AMD modules.) You need to perform the leakage yourself.

Change your config to:

```
define("wicket-glue", ["wicket"], function (wicket) {
    Wkt = wicket; // Deliberately leak into the global space.
    return wicket;
});

require.config({    
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths: {
        'wicket': '/Vendor/Wicket/wicket',
        'wicketGmap3': '/Vendor/Wicket/wicket-gmap3'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            wicket: 'wicket-glue',
        },
        'wicket-glue': {
            wicket: 'wicket'
        }
    }
    shim: {
        wicketGmap3: {            
            deps: ['wicket']
        }          
    },
});
```

I've added a new module named `wicket-glue`. I often place such modules together with the configuration so that they don't require an additional data fetch. You could just as well put it in a separate file if you want. (If I did that, I'd remove the first argument to `define` though and name the file `wicket-glue.js` so that RequireJS takes the module name from the file name.)

I've also added a `map` which essentially says "in all modules, when the module `wicket` is required, load `wicket-glue` instead, but in `wicket-glue` when `wicket` is required, load `wicket`".

The net effect is that whenever `wicket` is required, `Wkt` will be leaked to the global space and `wicket-glue` should work fine.